# HTTP Status 500 when compiling JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In my JSF app, I get an HTTP Status 500 error when I access the url. It doesn't matter what web app I create. This error occurs on all my apps. I'm using Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 7 and Java EE 1.7

The problem always occurs at the same code which is the f:view line.

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 9

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 9

6: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
7:  <title>Login Page</title>
8: </head>
9: <f:view>
10:     <center>
11:     Hello World
12:     </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP looks somewhat strange - are you having a `body`tag around the view and are you referring to the tag library?

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:outputText value="Hello world!" />
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

(Adapted example taken from [JSF Toolbox](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_view.html))